# Run shell command inside ruby, attach STDIN to command input

Tags: ruby, shell

I'm running a long-running shell command inside ruby script like this:

```
Open3.popen2(command) {|i,o,t|
  while line = o.gets
   MyRubyProgram.read line
   puts line
  end
}
```

So I would be able to look at the command output in the shell window.

How do I attach STDIN to command input?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to:

1. Wait for the user input from STDIN
2. Wait for the output of the command from the `popen3 -- o`

You may need [`IO.select`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/IO.html#method-c-select) or other IO scheduler, or some other multi-task scheduler, such as `Thread`.

Here is a demo for the `Thread` approach:

```
require 'open3'

Open3.popen3('ruby -e "while line = gets; print line; end"') do |i, o, t|
  tin = Thread.new do
    # here you can manipulate the standard input of the child process
    i.puts "Hello"
    i.puts "World"
    i.close
  end

  tout = Thread.new do
    # here you can fetch and process the standard output of the child process
    while line = o.gets
      print "COMMAND => #{line}"
    end
  end

  tin.join    # wait for the input thread
  tout.join   # wait for the output thread
end
```

Comment: I'm reluctant to use your code because I have no experience with thread synchronization in Ruby. Basically, I just want to be able to process output programmatically and to interact with the shell while I'm at it. Isn't there a simpler way to do that? What if I launch the shell and redirect a copy of output with `tee` to my program? Will it solve my problem?

Comment: @ArtShayderov I've updated the demo a bit and added some comment. You can save it to a Ruby file and test it. It should be clear where to manipulate the standard input and where to process the standard output now.

Comment: So I put reading STDIN inside tin block like that  `STDIN.each_char {|c| i.puts c}`?

Comment: @ArtShayderov Yes. Make sure 1) You terminate the input by EOF after you finish typing, that is, Ctrl-Z on windows or Ctrl-D on Linux. 2) You close the standard input of the child process (`i.close`) before you leave the `tin` block.

Comment: It works. But I'm testing different commands in linux and some of them (e.g. top) fail with message `failed tty get`.

Comment: @ArtShayderov `top` doesn't accept STDIN redirecting. You can run `top <some_text_file_name` to see the error